# Splitting a string in SSRS 2008 R2 using a custom code for three columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm splitting the string to break up a column that separated by | .
I want to split it into 3 columns.

> ATTN: Brian Adams | 343 Albert Ave | 17th Street

This is the code I have now

```
   Public Function GetAddress1 (ByVal a as String)
        Dim b() as string
        b=Split(a,"|")
        Dim str_1(b.Length) As String
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To b.Length - 1
            str_1(i) = b(i).Split("|")(0)
        Next
   return str_1
End Function


Public Function GetAddress2 (ByVal a as String)
        Dim b() as string
        b=Split(a,"|")
        Dim str_1(b.Length) As String
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 2 To b.Length - 1
            str_1(i) = b(i).Split("|")(0)
        Next
   return str_1
End Function

Public Function GetAttention (ByVal a as String)
        Dim b() as string
        b=Split(a,"|")
        Dim str_1(b.Length) As String
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To b.Length - 2
            str_1(i) = b(i).Split("|")(0)
        Next
   return str_1

End Function
```

The functions work when there's only 2 values **ATTN: Brian Adams |
343 Albert Ave** but when there's three values the `GetAddress1` will grab info to the right of the the second `|` and get the `GetAddress2` value.

Comment: Have you considered doing this at the dataset, rather than in a function in SSRS? There are literally 100's of answers on how to split a string in T-SQL on SO.

Comment: The original data has char(13) and char(10)  that I had to replace with |.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Function GetAddress1 (ByVal a as String)
        Dim b() as string
        b=Split(a,"|",2)
        Dim str_1(b.Length) As String
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 1 To b.length - 1 
            str_1(i) = b(i).Split("|")(0)
        Next
   return str_1
End Function
```

Writing the **,2** located the second value in the string without throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

So you want only the first 2 elements from the array?

```
    Dim TheSring As String = "ATTN: Brian Adams | 343 Albert Ave | 17th Street"
    Dim StrAry() As String = TheSring.Split("|")

    For i As Integer = 0 To 1
        TextBoxOutput.Text &= StrAry(i).Trim & Environment.NewLine
    Next
```